# insert xml into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

hello i try to insert some data in xml file into a mysql, i need to inser data codice into reference column and data qta in quantity column
Xml is:

```
<dispo>

<codice>CA031BL</codice>

<arrivi>

  <arrivo>

    <maga>B</maga>

    <data>2020-04-01</data>

    <qta>0</qta>

  </arrivo>

</arrivi>
```

```
<codice>CA031BL</codice>

<arrivi>

  <arrivo>

    <data>2020-04-01</data>

    <maga>C</maga>

    <qta>30</qta>

  </arrivo>
  </dispo>
```

in php file i've insert this:
connection to mysql db work
simplexml load seems work
if i insert number insead of $quantity and $ reference it's work but how can i insert right column of xml file?

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "psw", "db");

$affectedRow = 0;

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://......./dispo2.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {
    $quantity = $row->qta;
    $reference = $row->codice;

    $sql = "UPDATE ps_stock_available set quantity = '$quantity' where id_product = (SELECT id_product from ps_product where reference in ('$reference')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (! empty($result)) {
        $affectedRow ++;
    } else {
        $error_message = mysqli_error($conn) . "\n";
    }
}
?>
<h2>Insert XML Data to MySql Table Output</h2>
<?php
if ($affectedRow > 0) {
    $message = $affectedRow . " records inserted";
} else {
    $message = "No records inserted";
}

?>
<style>
body {  
    max-width:550px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.affected-row {
    background: #cae4ca;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: #bdd6bd 1px solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #6e716e;
}
.error-message {
    background: #eac0c0;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: #dab2b2 1px solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #5d5b5b;
}
</style>
<div class="affected-row"><?php  echo $message; ?></div>
<?php if (! empty($error_message)) { ?>
<div class="error-message"><?php echo nl2br($error_message); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

i need to insert also this before importing data because i've to insert in quantity of mysql the sum of value qta of my xml with the same code:

```
 select `reference`, sum(`quantity`)
    from `ps_product_attribute`
    group by `reference`
```

Comment: Did you check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html ? Do you use MySQL 8 or 5? I also suggest you delete any non-essential code from your example, especially CSS, it makes reading your question simpler.

Comment: What's the exact problem with that code? Why do you want to insert data using a `SELECT` query?

Answer (score 0):

When loading data from SimpleXML and just using

```
$quantity = $row->qta;
```

The value in quantity will be a SimpleXMLElement, you can check this using

```
var_dump($quantity);
```

which will show

```
class SimpleXMLElement#6 (0) {
}
```

So if you want to use these values in most other cases, then you may need to cast them to strings...

```
$quantity = (string)$row->qta;
```

This issue can hide itself as things like `echo` will automatically cast the values to strings to output them.